# Complete empty cells of a table with specific value SAS

Tags: date, sas, cell

I'm working on a table in SAS with a column that contains dates (FENTREGA in the picture), i want to complete the empty cells of this column with "Empty", can you help me with the code?
This is the structure of my table, the column i need to use is FENTREGA.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You cannot. That column type is numeric with a date format and the value EMPTY is a character value. You can apply a custom format though to have the . show as EMPTY.

Answer (score 1):

Since your column is numeric you cannot put text in the same column. However, you can make the period appear as the text EMPTY if you use a custom format.
Or you can make the whole column text, but then you cannot do date operations/calculations on the column without converting it back.

```
proc format;
value empty_dates
. = 'Empty'
Other = [mmddyyd10.];
run;

proc sql;
....

t1.FENTREGA format=empty_dates.,
....
```

EDIT: Fully tested solution, works as expected

```
DATA have;
informat FENTREGA mmddyy10.;
format FENTREGA date9.;
input  FENTREGA;
datalines;
 12/10/2003
 10/15/2006
 07/20/2010
 05/11/2006
 10/01/2006
 07/03/2012
 05/08/2015
 .
 .
 .
 .
;
RUN;
 
proc format;
value empty_dates
. = 'Empty'
Other = [mmddyyd10.];
run;

proc sql;
select
FENTREGA format=empty_dates.
from have;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you, i understand! but i get an error with the line "t1.FENTREGA format = empty_dates.," i get: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Show your actual error or check and see how your data/situation differs from the code above. It does work as you can see from the example above.